# Hot to load @IBOutlet before ViewController is displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, iboutlet

I am working on app that has 2 tabs (and 2 `ViewControllers`):

- first loads with app launch and contains some controls to input data (let's call it `HomescreenVC`)
- second is a calendar made up with `UITableView` that is connected via `@IBOutlet` to this tab's `ViewController` (let's call it `CalendarVC`): `@IBOutlet weak var calendarTableView: UITableView!`. This calendar can be used to view history of input data.

I want the calendar to update its data when user saves input on the first tab (`HomescreenVC`). For that purpose I use a delegate method that tells the `CalendarVC` to reload it's calendar:

In `HomescreenVC`:

```
calendarDelegate = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? CalendarViewController
calendarDelegate?.updateCalendar()
```

In `CalendarVC`:

```
func updateCalendar() {
    calendarTableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is that unless user had previously opened the tab with calendar (thus calling its `viewDidLoad()` method), its tableView outlet will return `nil` causing app to crash when delegate method is called. Of course, a simple solution would be to make the calendar first tab appearing on launch, but this will confront the logic of UX.

I've also tried to instantiate the CalendarVC using storyboard ID:

```
calendarDelegate = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CalendarVC") as! CalendarViewController
```

But it has no effect on instantiating outlets.

So my question is how to load the tableView from another `ViewController` before its `viewDidLoad()` gets called?

Comment: Basically you don't.  You need to look into separating your data model from the view controllers.  That way when the second calendar view controller loads it just looks up the required values in the data model and displays them.

Comment: Maybe you can try force-loading the `view` by accessing it: `calendarDelegate.view` and then call `calendarDelegate?.updateCalendar()`.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, you're absolutely right - with delegation I completely messed up the MVC. Just proves the point that if something fails to work, it should probably not work that way)) I am posting solution as own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   calendarDelegate = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as?  CalendarViewController
   if(calendarDelegate != nil)
   {

          calendarDelegate?.updateCalendar()
   }
```

Also if this updateCalendar isn't yet called don't worry about updating that data as when it first launch , data showed will be up to date if you're sharing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using not-yet-loaded delegate, I introduced a static toggle variable to my model struct:

```
static var calendarNeedsUpdate = false
```

When user submits new data, this variable toggles to `true`. Then, when calendar tab is opened, I use the `viewWillAppear()` method of `CalendarVC`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
...
   if ModelStruct.calendarNeedsUpdate {
      calendarTableView.reloadData()
      ModelStruct.calendarNeedsUpdate = false
   }
}
```

Comment: Also set `calendarNeedsUpdate = false` in `viewDidLoad` because there is no need to reload the first time the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose slightly different approach by small change in design.

If you can change TabBar controller with something else, you can create UIContainerView on first tab (view controller) that embeds second view controller and simply hide it on first tab viewWillAppear().

When second tab needs to be displayed, you can simply change second tab's isHidden = false or do any nice animation you want.

Back to your goal, when you need to access 2nd tab view controller, it is already instantiated and all IBOutlets are linked already.

The bottleneck of this approach is that you need to create tab bar icon bar by yourself.